# Has anyone successfully ran the raspberry pi camera v2 on Android on the rpi3?

Tags: pi-3, camera, raspicam, android

I have made an app that uses facial recognition, and I would like to run it on an RPi3. I have exhausted my google-fu in trying to find an Android build that works well on the RPi3 (it's the only Pi that I think will be powerful enough to run the app), and I have found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-rpi/fgyEhn5vxbg

Looks like there are some people who have android running on the RPi3, but I'm not sure whether the [Camera](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/) will be a plug and play solution that I am looking for, or whether it will require me to write drivers/kernels/other complicated things that I have no experience in.

So my question is: has anyone installed android on an RPi3, and successfully used the Camera Module V2 with it? I would much prefer not to use a USB camera for this application.

Comment: There's several things required to get the camera module working on any given Linux based platform. The first is the camera firmware (/boot/start_x.elf on Raspbian), the second is whatever kernel module exposes the /dev/vchiq device (sorry, not sure off the top of my head), and then whatever userspace libraries you need (I'm most familiar with libmmal, but there are a couple of V4L2 drivers available, and OpenMAX is another possibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with Android Things, the RPI3 and the Camera v2 it's basically a plug and play solution; no kernel modifications or user libraries needed, just java code with the standard Android APIs.

See the Android Things documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/things/training/doorbell/camera-input.html)

You may have to modify your app to run on Android Things however.

Comment: Do you know whether this is true only for Android Things or for normal Android, too?